# AngularJS $viewValue is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I'm pretty new with Angular and tried to implement this Angular buttons-checkbox binding: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ye6At/390/), however I got an error **"Cannot read property '$viewValue' of undefined"**
The *ctrl* is showing as undefined when I debug on the browser console. I tried many answers on StackOverflow however is still stuck after hours of trying.

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" ng-model="myModel.optionA"
            ng-show="myModel.optionA" class="btn">A</button>
    <button type="button" ng-model="myModel.optionB"
            ng-show="myModel.optionB" class="btn">B</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
app.controller("productCatalogController", ["$scope", "$http", "$compile", "$timeout", 
function($scope, $http, $compile, $timeout) { ... }



app.directive('button', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        'ngModel': '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        if (!element.parent('[data-toggle="buttons-checkbox"].btn-group').length) {
            return;
        }

        scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            element.toggleClass('active', ctrl.$viewValue);

        });

        element.bind('click', function(e) {
            scope.$apply(function(scope) {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(!ctrl.$viewValue);
            });
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
     }
    }

 });
```

Comment: the fiddle you posted is **functional**;  what is different between the fiddle and your code?

Comment: @Claies I bound the ngModel with **require** as suggested by Daniel below, it looks like that is the only difference.  It got rid of the initial error, BUT it is showing new error:  "Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'button', can't be found!". 
I used this syntax:
`require: 'ngModel'`

Comment: It would be wiser to choose a name for the directive other than `button`. Otherwise the directive will attach itself to every button in the template including ones that you don't want to act like checkboxes. That is likely the problem. A button that is not a checkbox now wants an `ng-model` directive.

Comment: @georgeawg YES that was definitely the problem, all buttons were trying to get the ng-model directive. I renamed the directive and now it's **working perfectly.** Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't simply bind to `ngModel` with `scope`. Use `require` as such:

```
'require': 'ngModel'
```

Comment: I did this and it got rid of the error, however the buttons are shown even when both checkbox are un-checked :/

Comment: @nfiona what do you mean? your fiddle seems to work, buttons are shown/hidden based on the checkbox values

Comment: @Daniel That was someone else's fiddle and I tried to implement it in my project. Sorry, should've clarified. Found the solution from _georgeawg_ above. Thanks!